# How to put regexp inside proto struct in golang?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a tree-like structure, that has string regexp and I want Go compiled `*regexp.Regexp` to be part of it as well, in order to run algorithms on the tree. When I marshal and pass it to a different machine I may just recompile it again from the string. What is the correct way to do that, how to force protobuf to store pointers in a structure, that it ideally wont marshal? (the only way that i see is to make `uint64` field and cast its value to/from  `*Regexp`)

pseudo-code (because required wanted features seems to be not in the language):

```
// struct generated by protoc
type ProtoMessage struct {
    Data string
    Source string
    Regexp uint64 // should not be marshalled, should be forcefully omitted from payload when doing proto.Marshal, ideally it should be *regexp.Regexp
    Left   *ProtoMessage
    Right  *ProtoMessage
}

func main() {
    // sender computer doSend():
    mSrc := &ProtoMessage{Data:"its meee!!!", Source: "hello.+world"}
    payload, _ := proto.Marshal(m)

    //receiver computer: onRecv()
    mDst := new(ProtoMessage)
    proto.Unmarshal(payload, mDst)
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(mDst.Source)
    mDst.Regexp = uint64(unsafe.Pointer(r)) // not working btw

    TreeMatch = func(tree* ProtoMessage, line string) string {
        if *regexp.Regexp(t.Regexp).Match(line) { // not working line
            return t.Data
        }
        if tree.Left == nil {
            return ""
        }
        return TreeMatch(tree.Left, line)
    }

    assert( TreeMatch(mDst, "hello, world") == "its meee!!!") // panic if condition is false
}
```

With json marshal i can just pot a pointer to regexp and provide a tag `json:"-"` in order not to include this field into marshalled structure, and ofc its important feature of marshalling/unmarshalling system to stay efficient (eg use same structure to run algorithms on in, and avoid data copying after unmarshal). How can I do the same with protobuf?

Comment: Put the pattern in protobuf, and recompile

Comment: the pattern is alredy in a protobuf, but when i receive tree i want to precompile everything and store compiled result in a same tree, (which is made of protobuf-generated structures), so when i traverse the tree I can do regexp match

Comment: Maybe if you can include some code examples your question can be better understood.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store a pointer in a protobuf, as the recipient is likely a different computer. Even if you could, you'd get a panic as soon as you tried to dereference the pointer. Easiest thing to do would be just pass the RegExp string, then compile again at the destination:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"
)

func main() {
   v := structpb.NewStringValue("hello.+world")
   b, err := proto.Marshal(v)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", b) // "\x1a\fhello.+world"
}
```

Note: you can't hack around this with Gob either:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/gob"
   "regexp"
)

func main() {
   re := regexp.MustCompile("hello.+world")
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   if err := gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(re); err != nil {
      panic(err) // type regexp.Regexp has no exported fields
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I can store a pointer in protobuf, your statement is false..

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, you just have to have any pointer inside your struct (no matter if its marshalling or not, you are not using its unmarshalled value on receiver side):

proto declaration:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package main;
option go_package = ".;main";

message Empty {
}

message ProtoMessage {
    string data    = 1;
    string source = 2;
    Empty regexp = 3; // ideally should not be marshalled at all, like `json:"-"` but for protobuf
    ProtoMessage left = 4;
    ProtoMessage right = 5;
}
```

testing code:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

type Empty struct {
    //state         protoimpl.MessageState
    //sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    //unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields
}

// struct generated by protoc
type ProtoMessage struct {
    //state         protoimpl.MessageState
    //sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    //unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Data   string        `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=data,proto3" json:"data,omitempty"`
    Source string        `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=source,proto3" json:"source,omitempty"`
    Regexp *Empty        `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=regexp,proto3" json:"regexp,omitempty"` // ideally should not be marshalled at all, like `json:"-"` but for protobuf
    Left   *ProtoMessage `protobuf:"bytes,4,opt,name=left,proto3" json:"left,omitempty"`
    Right  *ProtoMessage `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=right,proto3" json:"right,omitempty"`
}

func (p *ProtoMessage) GetCompiledRegexp() *regexp.Regexp {
    return (*regexp.Regexp)(unsafe.Pointer(p.Regexp))
}

func (p *ProtoMessage) SetCompiledRegexp(r *regexp.Regexp) {
    p.Regexp = (*Empty)(unsafe.Pointer(r))
}

func TreeMatch(tree *ProtoMessage, line string) string {
    if tree.GetCompiledRegexp().Match([]byte(line)) { // not working line
        return tree.Data
    }
    if tree.Left == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return TreeMatch(tree.Left, line)
}

func TestTreeMatch(t *testing.T) {
    //happening at receiver side: imagine its proto.Unmarshal(payload, receiverMsg)
    receiverMsg := &ProtoMessage{
        Data:   "its meee!!!",
        Source: "hello.+world",
    }
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(receiverMsg.Source)
    receiverMsg.SetCompiledRegexp(r)
    if TreeMatch(receiverMsg, "helloworld") != "" {
        t.Fatalf("TreeMatch gives non-existing match!")
    }
    if TreeMatch(receiverMsg, "hello, world") != "its meee!!!" {
        t.Fatalf("TreeMatch is not working!")
    }
}

type ProtoMessageDirect struct {
    Data   string
    Source string
    Regexp *regexp.Regexp
    Left   *ProtoMessageDirect
    Right  *ProtoMessageDirect
}

func (p *ProtoMessageDirect) GetCompiledRegexp() *regexp.Regexp {
    return p.Regexp
}

func (p *ProtoMessageDirect) SetCompiledRegexp(r *regexp.Regexp) {
    p.Regexp = r
}

func TreeMatchDirect(tree *ProtoMessageDirect, line string) string {
    if tree.GetCompiledRegexp().Match([]byte(line)) { // not working line
        return tree.Data
    }
    if tree.Left == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return TreeMatchDirect(tree.Left, line)
}

func BenchmarkRegexpCast(b *testing.B) {
    receiverMsg := &ProtoMessage{
        Data:   "its meee!!!",
        Source: "hello.+world",
    }
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(receiverMsg.Source)
    receiverMsg.SetCompiledRegexp(r)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        TreeMatch(receiverMsg, "hello, world")
    }
}

func BenchmarkRegexpDirect(b *testing.B) {
    receiverMsg := &ProtoMessageDirect{
        Data:   "its meee!!!",
        Source: "hello.+world",
    }
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(receiverMsg.Source)
    receiverMsg.SetCompiledRegexp(r)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        TreeMatchDirect(receiverMsg, "hello, world")
    }
}
```

`TestTreeMatch` is passing and Benchmarks shows that such a cast does not create any meaningful difference:

```
BenchmarkRegexpCast-20           2741786           376.7 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkRegexpDirect-20         3075280           377.0 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
```